# How to take the limit: x goes to infinity, when x appears in the bounds of an integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

To be specific, I am wondering how to take the limit of the following expression:
\begin{align}
L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{2x} \int_{-x}^x dh \int_{-x}^x dg \ f(g-h),
\end{align}
where $f(g-h)$ is a well behaved function.

I can change coordinates to $u=g-h$ and $v=h$; the ‎Jacobian of this transformation is J=1, so the limit becomes
\begin{align}
L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{2x} \int_{-x}^x dv \int_{-x-v}^{x-v} du \ f(u).
\end{align}

At this point I'm stuck. I believe, by looking at it, the limit is
\begin{align}
L = 
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \ f(u),
\end{align}
but I would really like a way to see this formally. It would be nice to know of general methods to solve the above limit as well.

Comment: Do you have any more information about your function $f$? or are these the only hypotheses?

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks:
Yeah, in the case I am considering
\begin{align}
f(u) = p(u) U(u) \rho U^(u)^{\dagger},
\end{align}
where $p(u)$ is a probability distribution, $\rho$ is a density matrix, and $U(u)$ is a unitary operator parameterized by $u$.

Having said that, I think whatever method used to evaluate the limit when $f$ is just a functions from the reals to the reals, should carry over fairly easily to the case I'm considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can stick to simple one variable changes of variable. Let $F$ be an antiderivative for $f.$ Then

$$\int_{-x}^x\int_{-x}^x f(s-t)\,ds\,dt = \int_{-x}^x\int_{-x-t}^{x-t} f(s)\,ds\,dt$$ $$ = \int_{-x}^x (F(x-t)-F(-x-t)) \,dt = \int_0^{2x}(F(t)-F(-t))\, dt.$$

Thus the expression we're interested in is

$$\frac{\int_0^{2x}(F(t)-F(-t))\, dt}{2x}.$$

By L'Hopital, the limit of this equals the limit of $F(2x)-F(-2x) \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it's right, but I don't see how you went from the second last equality to the last one. Starting with the second last equality, and making the change of variables $y=x-t$:
\begin{align}
\int_{-x}^x \Big( F(x-t) - F(-x-t) \Big) dt &= \int_0^{2x} \Big( F(y) - F(y-2x) \Big) dy,
\end{align}
which differs from what you have above.

Comment: Applying L'Hopital rule to the above yields
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}  \frac{1}{2x} \int_0^{2x} \Big( F(y) - F(y-2x) \Big) dt &= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{2x} \Big( F(y) - F(y-2x) \Big) dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x\to \infty}\left[  2 \Big( F(2x) - F(0) \Big)  +  \int_0^{2x} 2 F'(y-2x) \Big) dy \right] \\
&=  \lim_{x\to \infty} \left[     F(2x) - F(0)   +   F(0) - F(-2x)  \right] \\
&=  \lim_{x\to \infty} \left[ F(2x) -   F(-2x)    \right]\\
&= \int^{\infty}_\infty f(u) du,
\end{align}
Would you agree with the above? Thanks again :-)

Comment: It's much easier in $\int_{-x}^x F(-x-t) \,dt $ to just let $t= t'-x$ to get $\int_{0}^{2x} F(-t') \,dt'.$

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of integration, so you have 
$$\int_{-2x}^{0}duf(u)\int_{-x-u}^{x}dv+\int_0^{2x}udf(u)\int_{-x}^{x-u}dv$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how you can swap the order of integration. The bounds on the inner integral depend on the integration variable of the outer integral. Do you mind explaining that part?

Comment: My first goes were wrong.  Draw the parallelogram in $(u,v)$ space, which I think has vertices (0,-x),(2x,-x),(0,x),(-2x,x). That is two isosceles right triangles.  for each triangle, work out the limits with $u$ the outer variable, then the limits for $v$.